# PHP popup alert

Tags: javascript, php

I am using WPforms on a WordPress site. I have two checkboxes and you are only allowed to check one box. if you select two you a warning you have exceeded the number of allowed selections: 1.

[image]

I would like this as a POPUP alert or warning. I searched the code and found the following

```
if ( $choice_limit > 0 && $count_choices > $choice_limit ) {
// Generating the error.$error = wpforms_setting( 'validation-check-limit', esc_html__( 'You have exceeded the number of allowed selections: {#}.', 'wpforms-lite' ) );
$error = str_replace( '{#}', $choice_limit, $error );        }
```

I tried this

```
if ( $choice_limit > 0 && $count_choices > $choice_limit ) {
            // Generating the error.
            $error = wpforms_setting( 'validation-check-limit', esc_html__( 'You have exceeded the number of allowed selections: {#}.', 'wpforms-lite' ) );
            echo '<script>alert("You have exceeded the number of allowed selections: {#}.")</script>'; 
            $error = str_replace( '{#}', $choice_limit, $error );
        }
```

This is in class-settings-php

```
'validation-check-limit'           => [
                    'id'      => 'validation-check-limit',
                    'name'    => esc_html__( 'Checkbox Selection Limit', 'wpforms-lite' ),
                    'type'    => 'text',
                    'default' => esc_html__( 'You have exceeded the number of allowed selections: {#}.', 'wpforms-lite' ),
                ],
```

This is in class-frontend.php

```
'val_checklimit'             => wpforms_setting( 'validation-check-limit', esc_html__( 'You have exceeded the number of allowed selections: {#}.', 'wpforms-lite' ) ),
```

And this is in the class-checkbox.php

```
if ( $choice_limit > 0 && $count_choices > $choice_limit ) {
            // Generating the error.
            $error = wpforms_setting( 'validation-check-limit', esc_html__( 'You have exceeded the number of allowed selections: {#}.', 'wpforms-lite' ) );
            $error = str_replace( '{#}', $choice_limit, $error );
        }
```

Comment: This may be an obvious answer you've already thought about but are you able to switch the checkboxes to a radio? This would eliminate the need for a validation all together.

Comment: I want validation. The above picture was only an example. I have 40 checkboxes. You are only allowed to select 4. If you select more than 4 I would like a noticeable popup. On some screens, you cannot see the warning as there are too many checkboxes.